# JsonPath get length of array after filter

Tags: jsonpath

Hi I want get legth of array after Filter with JsonPath.

Is it possible ?

My filter is `$.issues.[?(@.severity == 'MAJOR')].length()`

My Json is

```html
{
  "issues": [
        {
            "severity": "MAJOR"
        },
                {
            "severity": "MINOR"
        },
                {
            "severity": "MAJOR"
        },
                {
            "severity": "MAJOR"
        },
                {
            "severity": "MAJOR"
        }
]
  
}
```

Comment: Can you please tag your question with the language you are working in?  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging.  In the original JSONPath proposal http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ a query returns *`(array|false)` : Array holding either values or normalized path expressions matching the input path expression, which can be used for lazy evaluation. `false` in case of no match.*  So there is nothing that returns the count of matches in the proposal itself.  But maybe your language & framework supports something.  Or you can just count the number of items returned afterwards.

Comment: What about Jayway JsonPath implementation: the following JsonPath expression seems to be valid yet it returns incorrect result: [see sample](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..book[?(@.author%20=~%20/.*REES/i)].length())

Comment: @begie that example returns the count of keys of the map (category, author, title, price).

Comment: It's been some time but I believe that's why my comment says incorrect result is returned...

Comment: Any update on this? I think length is just for basic approaches

Comment: @dbc that's not a valid question, the poster is looking for an answer that is done completely within jsonpath.

Answer (score 4):

Possible workaround for [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) implementation

```
$.length($.issues.[?(@.severity == 'MAJOR')].length())
```